# Template variable, read a custom instance directly in template

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I am aware you can read specific instances of a template variable by using the `read` property of a `@ViewChild` decorator :

```
@ViewChild('child', { read: CustomComponent }) component: CustomComponent;
```

I am currently using a [Material card](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview) and I give it a template variable. What I want is to scroll to the bottom of that card at every keydown on the inner textarea :

```
<mat-card #card>
  <textarea (keydown)="scrollCardToBottom($event, card)"></textarea>
</mat-card>
```

Is it possible to consider `card` as an ElementRef directly from the template ? Right now, it is considered a `MatCard`, and I have to use the decorator to transform it into an ElementRef ...

Comment: @yurzui thank you, so no solution available right now ... Got it ! Feel free to post an answer so that I can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also miss this feature but unfortunately there is no solution right now to force template reference variable to be `ElementRef` rather than directive instance on a template side.

See also:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21089